# why i didnt show data from firebase in my preview rendered

Tags: javascript, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, preview

I can see My data from the database since firebase when I deploy but not in the previsualizer is it normal?  I'm pretty sure it's not the right way to display data but it's the only one I've ever done

The correct line to add to add fake itmes but not work

[print capture](https://gyazo.com/22422a41f0d1e1bd538a70f8a7856715)

---

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
compatibility/2006"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance x:Object}"
mc:Ignorable="d
```

---

```
 <ListView x:Name="listIdeas"
                  ItemTapped="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<TextCell Detail="{Binding Titre}" Text="{Binding Description}" />-->
                    <ViewCell x:Name="listIdeas">
                        <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Titre}" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Vote}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 // xaml.CS
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var allIdeas = await firebaseHelper.GetAllIdeas();
        listIdeas.ItemsSource = allIdeas;
    }

 // Helpers
 FirebaseClient firebase = new 
 FirebaseClient("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");

    public async Task<List<ItemsModel>> GetAllIdeas()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Ideas")
          .OnceAsync<ItemsModel>()).Select(item => new ItemsModel
          {
              Titre = item.Object.Titre,
              Description = item.Object.Description,
              Vote = item.Object.Vote
          }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: If you mean the Preview Panel within the Visual Studio IDE, yes that is normal as it is just an XAML previewer. It execute you code you would need to build, deploy and run it on a device|emulator|simulator for that...

Comment: Yes that's right. so how do you do the design without visual

Comment: The previewer supports design time / fake data to help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/design-time-data

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to work in my situation but the links thank you for the link you gave but it returns errors ca still put me on the way and I added the correct code if it can help someone else. for me even without error it does not work and he asks me delclass does not have default paramterless constructor

Comment: To contourn the problem you can add a fake data in a second initializecomponent but before the original 

 //  DEFAULT TEXT
        int fauxvote = 0;
        int moyenne = 5;
        public ItemDetailsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyTitre.Text = "titre";
            MyVote.Text = fauxvote.ToString() + " / " + moyenne.ToString();
        }

//REAL INITIALIZECOMPONENT

public ItemDetailsPage(string Titre, string Description, int Vote)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
}